# Warp an image into a quad region of another image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, contour

I have an image and i know four coordinates of that image, now i just want to put another small image on the contour formed by these four points. This contour is almost a square.
Is there a way to fill this contour points with the image?

I tried to create a rectangle but i can't create a rectangle using more than one point.
I'm stuck. Can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume that you want to "warp" an image (let's call it `img`) into a quad placed in another image (let's call it `canvas`) -- i.e. you basically want to do this:

[image]

First, you need to find the transformation (matrix) `T` between the rectangular image (`img`) and the destination quad (let's call it `warpedImg`):

```
cv::Mat T = getPerspectiveTransform(imgCorners,     // std::vector<cv::Point2f> that contains img's vertices -- i.e. (0, 0) (0,img.rows) (img.cols, img.rows) (img.cols, 0)
                                    warpedCorners); // std::vector<cv::Point2f> that contains warpedImg's vertices
```

Then, you can use `T` to generate `warpedImg` from `img`:

```
cv::Mat warpedImg;
cv::warpPerspective(img, warpedImg, T, canvas.size());
```

Finally, to "paste" `warpedImg` onto `canvas`, you can first "mask" the quad region in `canvas`:

```
cv::fillConvexPoly(canvas, warpedCorners, cv::Scalar::all(0), CV_AA);
```

Then apply an "or" operation:

```
cv::bitwise_or(warpedImg, canvas, canvas);
```

That's it!

Comment: You sir are amazing.I completely understood this concept and it worked like a charm. Thank you.